# Looking for a (free) personal knowledgebase application with tagging (Windows)

Tags: windows, gratis, knowledge-base, tags

I want to store notes/articles (mostly rich text but ideally images too) and tag and date them (dates would be arbitrary and typed manually). Incremental search on any combination of tags, note content and date would pull up matching notes either as a clickable list of note titles or as one combined view of all the matching notes (as if the matching notes had been copied into a single Word document, with note titles acting as headings).

The aim is to save a couple of hundred research notes on a company (e.g. news releases, org chart, my own notes, possibly imported PDFs of quarterly financials) and do searches like: notes dated April-Dec 2020 tagged 'strategy' and containing 'C?O' in the content (? being a wildcard). Word is my main tool and it's almost like I just need to be able to tag/date individual sections of a Word document and be able to search or fold them.

Googling finds things like Evernote, OneNote, Zotero, Trello, etc. but they don't quite fit (unless I'm not appreciating that they could be used for this). Maybe I just need a simple database?

Secondary requirements are that it's fairly simple, quick/crisp to use, uses Word-compatible rich text, and has fully customisable keyboard shortcuts and fonts.

Comment: Many people attempting to answer this will start with a web search and find the same apps you mention. It would help if you would [edit] the question to include information as to _how_ the apps you have looked at fail to meet your needs adequately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe OBSIDIAN could be a decent choice for your use case. However, it is based on MARKDOWN and I'm not sure if there are plugins which add RTF support. You could create a note called 2024-03-01 and link to it from other notes which would allow you to see all notes that link to 2024-03-01 when you open it. You can also use search. I'm just not sure if more advanced searches you are describing are possible (though there may exist plugins for that). I use Obsidian and have a system where I have a note for each object and link to other objects from each one. I have notes for movies, games, websites, apps, tasks, people and everything else. I also created my own helper program/tool which allows me to do stuff like custom searches and more.

So... looking into OBSIDIAN might be a good idea, but it may not have exactly all of the functionality you desire. Many of the features you need might be possible to achieve with plugins or (if you are a coder and have time) you could even create your own tools for stuff that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Give [TagSpaces](https://github.com/tagspaces/tagspaces) a try.

[image: Tag Spaces Image]

It both offers tagging for files and taking notes.